# How did this question end up status-review?

Tags: bug, tags, suggested-edits, moderator-tags

Only moderators should be able to add status tags. However, it seems a normal user [was able to add the status-review tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/44235) to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/277917/245360).

I have tried to reproduce this, but I wasn't able to do it as normal user or anonymous user.

The user seems to be an employee but it seems he is missing his diamond. He is able to make the tag change, but he still goes through review...

Comment: I noticed the same 2 days ago and left a [comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278752/titles-with-mathjax-break-in-the-related-questions#comment902876_278752).

Comment: He receiving +2 rep for the edits and his [profile](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/225016/pawe%C5%82?tab=topactivity) says `0 posts edited`. That also confusing.

Comment: Indeed. Very confusing...